# Removing "..." button from PropertyGrid collection property

Tags: c#, collections, propertygrid, uitypeeditor

I'm trying to change the way collection properties appear in a Winforms PropertyGrid.

Instead of having

```
MyList | (Collection) [...]
```

And having to press on the button to show the CollectionEditor.
I'm expanding the List as an ExpandableObjectConverter. But I still get the [...] button. So now it looks something like this.

```
[+] MyList | (2 Items) [...]
    Item 1 | Value
    Item 2 | Value
```

Eventually I'd like to replace this [...] for an Add button. I just don't quite know where to start. If I understand correctly, the CollectionEditor is the window displayed when I press the [...]. So what is the object I need to override to remove and add my own buttons.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inherit a new class from the `CollectionEditor` and override the `GetEditStyle` to return `None` to prevent the "..." button from showing.

Also unfortunaly you can't add an `Add` button using the standard propertygrid. You can choose from  "...", down arrow or no button.

```
class CustomEditor : CollectionEditor
{
  public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
  {
    return UITypeEditorEditStyle.None;
  }
}
```

You can apply this new editor the propery using the following attribute:

```
[EditorAttribute(typeof(CustomEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
```